# React component is re rendering despite using useCallback hook

Tags: reactjs

My code:

App jsx is the parent component

**App.jsx**|

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedUnits, setSelectedUnits] = useState([]);

  const updateSelectedUnits = useCallback((unitId) => {
    const newSelectedUnits = selectedUnits.includes(unitId)
      ? selectedUnits.filter((u) => u !== unitId) // remove item
      : [...selectedUnits, unitId];
    setSelectedUnits(newSelectedUnits);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table updateSelectedUnits={updateSelectedUnits} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And,

Table jsx is the child component which is rerendering whenever I clicked on any of the TD. Since, `updateSelectedUnits`, just update the states, and this state is not passed to child components, I am little confused, why it is still rerendering. On top of that I have also used `useCallback`, not sure if it is something I have done correctly though.

**Table.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const Table = ({ updateSelectedUnits }) => {
  const handleUnitClick = (event, unitId) => {
    //add class to td
    updateSelectedUnits(unitId);
  };

  console.log("table rerendered");

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td onClick={(e) => handleUnitClick(e, "1")}>01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td onClick={(e) => handleUnitClick(e, "1")}>02</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Here, is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sinoussi-fhemgq?file=/src/Table.jsx). `Table` component is rerendering, and I want it to be prevent from rerendering

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.memo` to prevent the Table to be re-rendered.

`export default React.memo(Table)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using react version 18 which mounts the component, unmounts it and then mounts it again you can read more about it in the [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state)

I downgraded it to version 17 and it only renders once: [codesandbox react v17](https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-andras-mdmkeg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

It only happens in react 18 if you have `StrictMode` in `index.js`, removing it will only render the Table `once`

Comment: that was not my question, when you click on td, it should not mount at all, I am not talking about rerendering once or twice.

Answer (score -2):

`<Table/>` is always re-rendered because it's a child of `<App/>`, which gets re-rendered after its state update. There's no workaround about this.

EDIT: To avoid permanent calculation in your Table component, just memoize intensive computations with useMemo().

```js
  const computedData = React.useMemo(()=> {
    console.log("computedData running")
    return ["cool", "data"]
  }, [])

  console.log("computedData", computedData)
```

You will see that the log `computedData` will appear as expected after each click on a table cell, but it won't run an intensive computation more than once (the log `computedData running` will only fire once).

Rendering is not a bad thing. Memoization has a cost and should only be used for intensive computations. Also, add `selectedUnits` as an array dependency of `updateSelectedUnits` in App.tsx to avoid any memory leaks.

Comment: On sample, it seems not big issue, but I have quite big table component, with a lot of calulation going on each div. And taking a lot of time, how could I improve the performance on this case?